# How does one know that a problem is "model-free" in reinforcement learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, dqn

Consider [this slide](https://youtu.be/FgzM3zpZ55o?list=PLoROMvodv4rOSOPzutgyCTapiGlY2Nd8u&t=2705) from a Stanford lecture on reinforcement learning. It states that a model is

> the agent's representation of how the world changes in response to the agent's action.

I've been experimenting with Q-learning for simple problems such as OpenAI's [FrozenLake](https://gym.openai.com/envs/FrozenLake-v0/) and [Mountain Car](https://gym.openai.com/envs/MountainCar-v0/), which both are amenable to the Q-learning framework (the latter upon discretization). I consider the topologies of the lake and the mountain to be the "worlds" (aka. environments) in the two cases, respectively.

Q-learning is said to be ["model-free"](https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/_images/rl_algorithms_9_15.svg). Given the two examples above, is it because neither the lake's topology nor that of the mountain are changed by the actions taken?

Comment: Let me know if the answers to [this question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/4456/2444) answer your question. If your question is not "What does model-free mean?", then, please, edit your post to clarify what your question really is.

Comment: @nbro there is some overlap, but my question is much more concrete and dumbed-down: E.g., keeping in mind a specific example such as the car in the `MountainCar` problem, how can we tell that it is model-free? What would be the model in this case (e.g., a representation of the gravitational potential of the mountain)? As far as I see it, the Q-table that the agent (i.e. car) populates is an (implicit) representation of how the world changes, thereby making it model-based as per the definition.

Comment: If you understand the answers to the duplicate question, you will understand what a "model" is and, therefore, conclude that a value function is _not_ a model (or what we mean by "model" in RL). The model is the transition matrix (or function) of the MDP. If you have or use it, your algorithm is model-based, otherwise, it is not. For your algorithm to be model-based in MountainCar, you need to learn or know this transition matrix. If you don't know what a transition matrix is, I suggest that you look at the definition of an MDP.

Comment: Please, [edit your post](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/23745/2444) to clarify your actual question. If you are asking "what is a model in reinforcement learning", then ask that. And please explain how your question is different than the linked one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Q-learning is said to be "model-free". Given the two examples above, is it because neither the lake's topology nor that of the mountain are changed by the actions taken?

No. That's not why Q-learning is model-free. Q-learning assumes that the underlying environment (FrozenLake or MountainCar, for example) can be modelled as a **Markov decision process (MDP)**, which is a mathematical model that describes problems where decisions/actions can be taken and the outcomes of those decisions are at least partially stochastic (or random). More precisely, an MDP is composed of

- A set of actions $A$ (that the RL agent can take); for example, up and down, in some grid world
- A set of states $S$ (where the RL agent can be);
- A **transition function** $p(s_{t+1} = s' \mid s_{t} = s , a_t = a)$ (aka the **model**), which represents the probability of going to state $s'$ at time step $t+1$, given that at time step $t$ the RL agent is in the state $s$ and takes action $a$.
- A **reward function** $r(s, a, s')$ (sometimes also denoted as $r(s)$ or $r(s, s')$, although [these can have different semantics](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/10442/2444)); the reward function gives the reward (or reinforcement) to the RL agent when it takes an action in a certain state and moves to another state; the reward function can also be included in the transition function, i.e., often you will also see $p(s_{t+1} = s', r_{t+1} = r \mid s_{t} = s , a_t = a)$, and this is the **model**: this is what we mean by **model** in reinforcement learning, it's this $p$ (which is a probability distribution)!

A model-free algorithm is any algorithm that does not use or estimate this $p$. Q-learning, [if you look at its pseudocode](http://www.incompleteideas.net/book/RLbook2020.pdf#page=153), does not make use of this model. Q-learning estimates the value function $q(s, a)$ by interacting with the environment (taking actions and receiving rewards), but, meanwhile, it does not know or keep track of the dynamics (i.e. $p$) of the environment, and that's why it's model-free.

And, no, the value function is not what we mean by "model" in reinforcement learning. The value function is, as the name suggests, a function.

> How does one know that a problem is "model-free" in reinforcement learning?

A problem is not model-free or model-based. An **algorithm** is model-free or model-based. Again, a model-free algorithm does not use or estimate $p$, a model-based one uses (and/or estimates) it.

> Given the two examples above, is it because neither the lake's topology nor that of the mountain are changed by the actions taken?

No. As stated in the [other answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/23749/2444), you could apply the model-based algorithm Dyna-Q to these environments.

Answer (score 1):

A reinforcement learning algorithm is considered model based if it uses estimates of the environments dynamics to help learn. For instance, in the Tabular Dyna-Q algorithm, every time you visit a state action tuple you store in a look-up table the reward received and the next state transitioned to, and after every execution of an action you loop $n$ times to further back up your $Q$ table using these stored model values from the look-up table. I will attach a copy of the pseudo-code for an algorithm at the bottom of this post.

Algorithms like vanilla $Q$-learning are model free because they don't require a model of the environment to learn.

[image]

Comment: This answer is correct and I would upvote it, but if this question is a duplicate of [this one](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/4456/2444), I think it's better you answer there (although there are already many answers there, but none of them mentions Dyna-Q, apparently), because this will probably be closed as a duplicate of that one (I am just waiting for the OP's feedback).

Comment: My question is more about the physical intuition of what the model is, hence my specific reference to the concrete examples of `FrozenLake` and `MountainCar`. If a model is _"the agent's representation of how the world changes in response to the agent's action"_, then a Q-learning approach to `MountainCar` would be considered model-free because the car (i.e. the agent) does not have a representation of what the gravitational potential of the mountain is?